# How to indicate a URI component in a query string is a string instead of a number?

Tags: http

In the following query string:

```
?a=some string&b=100&c=333
```

how do I indicate that the 'b' query parameter is (also) a string (despite it looking like the number '100')? Is this the way?:

```
?a="some string"&b="100"&c=333
```

Or should the receiving end know that the query parameter 'b' is always of type String? I would like to prevent that latter case and keep things flexible.

Comment: query parameters don't have types. They're all just strings. Whether they should be interpreted as numbers or not is a question that has nothing to do with http and everything to do with what server-side programming framework you're using.

Comment: So the answer would be my latter guess. I was just wondering if there is maybe a common use to indicate a param's type, as the title shows. I guess not then. No need to downvote me thinks. Maybe I'll switch to encoded json objects then instead of regular query params. Thx.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a space (url encoded %20) before the strings:

```
?a=some string&b=%20100&c=333
```

And url decode followed by a trim on the receiving side.